# why i am getting all Nan's after coverting Netcdf data to arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, nan, python-xarray, netcdf4

I tried to convert dask array to normal array like numpy with netcdf data file, but i am getting all the values as Nan.
My code is

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('some.nc')
ds1=ds.load()
ds1
```

the output is

```
Data variables:
    AWCh1      (layer, latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
```

I expected corresponding data values instead of nan.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I finally got an update about my question. The lats and lons are basically gridded through out the earth, so the nan values belong to the Oceans and Seas.